# Do POST request programmatically

Tags: java, post

What is most easiest and convenient way to do a POST request to remote host programmatically using Java EE?

I need to POST some parameters and then read values of returned response parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org). It's a well-documented reliable library for doing HTTP interaction.

I would shy away from trying to write anything yourself via the basic Java SE APIs. For anything other than the *simplest* scenario you're going to find you're doing a lot of work.

Check out the examples documented [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/examples.html) - in particular the [POST example](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/examples/org/apache/http/examples/ElementalHttpPost.java).

Answer (score 0):

Definitely Apache Http Client! http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/

Answer (score 0):

with all the respect to Apache..
just use **HttpClient** and **PostMethod**.

easy as ABC

Answer (score 0):

Just open connection to your url and post your data.

```
URL wsurl = new URL(url);
URLConnection conn = wsurl.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
wr.write(data);
wr.flush();
// Get the response
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
   output.append(line);
}
wr.close();
rd.close();
```